# How to Bind Columns Property of a DataGrid Inside a UserControl?

Tags: wpf

I have a user control with a datagrid inside. I want the caller to be able to do something like this:

```
<local:MyControl>
    <local:MyControl.GridColumns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" />
    </local:MyControl.GridColumns>
</local:MyControl>
```

I tried to do something like this in my usercontrol definition:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <DataGrid Columns={Binding GridColumns} />
</UserControl>
```

I have a GridColumns property in the user control. It does not work.

How to do this correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Binding GridColumns does return a collection of DataGridTextColumn?  Do you need some of the advanced features of a DataGrid?  For a custom presentation I found the GridView easier to work with.  But I could never get it to bind directly to a columns collection.  I had to had to enumerate over the collection in code behind and add the columns one at a time.  I hope you get an answer to your question.

Comment: When I had the similar task, I created the derived ExtendedDataGrid class where I added the necessary property and implemented autogeneration of columns. But I worked with such bindings like <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding [0]}" />, I mean with bindings to array indexes. So can you post code of the `GridColumns` property of your viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind that property as it is not a dependency property, so just forward it:

```
<DataGrid Name="datagrid" />
```

```
public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> Columns
{
    get { return datagrid.Columns; }
}
```